# Red Gate SQL Prompt in Visual Studio not working?

Tags: ssdt, visual-studio

I have tried out SSDT Database project in Visual Studio, and with the SQL Prompt solution from Red Gate. It seems that the intellisense only works for SQL keywords like SELECT, WHERE etc, it does not provide intellisense for table names, column names etc.

Is there a trick to get this working? (Tried in both VS2015 and VS2017).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately SQLPrompt works on the connection to a database and not the database project. If you deploy your DB then SQLPrompt can pick it up the schema.

Its on the backlog as a research item currently https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/roadmap.

If you want project based intellisense then you need to disable SQL Prompt in VS

Comment: Hi. Just a quick question. I tried deploying, but still no intellisense via SQLPrompt with table-names or column-names. Do you know where/how I can check what connection is in use?

Answer (score 0):

Got a feedback from Red Gate that this does not work in Visual Studio yet.